# How to determine solvability of binary quadratic Diophantine equations of the form $x^2-axy+bx-y+c=0$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've been learning about Diophantine equations. I feel I have an understanding of standard linear equations and I am now working on binary, quadratic equations.

I'm trying to find integer solutions to equations of the form: $x^2-axy+bx-y+c=0$

For example: $x^2-29xy+27x-y+638373=0$

Before I take the time to try and find integers solutions, I'm hoping there is a trick to see if such solutions are even possible. Similar to how linear DE can determine solvability by $c|gcd(a,b)$.

Is there a simple way to determine the solvability of BQDE equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the quadratic form part   has square discriminant, therefore factors, and this continues ..

Taking $z=x-ay,$
$$ (1+ax)(1-ab -az) = 1 + a^2 c     $$

So, you need to factor$1 + a^2 c$ where both factors are $1 \pmod a$  or both $-1 \pmod a.$

If you get a pair of divisors that work, then check that $z \equiv x \pmod a$

Answer (score 1):

In the more general case, the equation,

$$x^2-axy+bx-y+c=0$$

has infinitely many *rational* solutions,

$$\begin{align}
x &= \frac{-n+(1-ab+a^2c)}{an}\\ 
y &= \frac{n^2+(ab-2)n+(1-ab+a^2c)}{a^2n}
\end{align}$$

for **arbitrary** $n$.

But you prefer *integer* solutions. So if you are lucky enough such that your $a=\pm 1$, then choose $n = \pm 1$, and you have your integers regardless of $b,c$.